# Proof Verification: Prove that $E$ is dense in $X$ if and only if $E \cap U \neq \emptyset$ for every nonempty open set $U \subset X$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Let $E$ be a subset of a metric space $(X,d)$. Prove that $E$ is dense in $X$ if and only if $E \cap U \neq \emptyset$ for every nonempty open set $U \subset X$.

We know that $\overline{E} = X$, so for every $x \in X$ there is a sequence $x_n \in E$ s.t $x_n \rightarrow x$. This implies every neighbourhood of x contains at least one point from $E$ (since  the sequence gets infinitely close to x). Which is equivalent to writing $$E \cap U \neq \emptyset$$ for every nonempty open set $U \subset X$.

I feel like there definitely is something missing in the proof. In particular I don't really understand why the subsets have to be open for this to hold. Explanations should probably also be done more rigorously with math instead of simply explaining in text, although Im not sure how to go about formalizing it more.

Comment: What happens if suppose you  take interesection of $E$ with singleton sets $\{x\}$, where $x \notin E $ ? It should be noted singleton sets are closed in metric spaces.

Comment: You're on the right track, but some of the details need fleshed out. The result you cite about the sequential characterization of closure may need to be proven if it's not the definition you're given. Also, don't forget for an iff statement you need to prove both ways. :)

Comment: Your argument shows that if $E$ is dense in $X$, then it meets every non-empty open set in $X$. To finish the proof, you have to prove the opposite implication: if $E\cap U\ne\varnothing$ for each non-empty open $U\subseteq X$, then $\operatorname{cl}E=X$.

Comment: Intuitively, an open set separates points from its boundary, in that you can always find $x\in U$ such that there is an open ball around $x$, fully contained in $U$, of some radius $\epsilon$. This would separate $x$ from $E$ if $E\cap U=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\overline E=X$. If $U$ is a non-empty open subset of $X$ and $u\in U$, then $U$ is a neighborhood of $u$ and therefore $U\cap E\ne\emptyset$.

And if $\overline E\ne X$, then let $U=\overline E^\complement$, which is a non-empty open set. And $E\cap U=\emptyset$.